# How to prevent page autoscrolling in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a listing page where i am displaying images of size 240*240. When i open the page in normal fullscreen mode it works fine but when i minimize or open dev tools the page autoscrolls to the bottom.The same page works fine in firefox.Can anyone help me out with this ?

Comment: Can you provide an example, JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: Do you have some `<input autofocus>` on your page?

Comment: @MartinAdámek i am not using autofocus

Comment: I would like to see an example that has your described problem.